# WordPress Custom Query for Most Commented Posts in the Past 7 Days

Tags: sql, wordpress, jquery-post

I'm trying to do a query on wpdb to get the posts commented on most in the past week... Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
$querystr = "SELECT comment_count, ID, post_title
        FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->comments wcomments
        WHERE wposts.ID = wcomments.comment_post_ID
        AND wcomments.comment_date >= CURDATE() - 7 
        GROUP BY wposts.ID
        ORDER BY comment_count DESC
        LIMIT 0 ,  10
 ";

 $pageposts = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
```

The query seems to get top commented posts of all time, instead of the top commented posts that have been commented on in the past week.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lonut, that takes care of the date range problem and most commented, but it wont select **only** the most commented posts *that were commented on* in the past X time interval.

This should do it:

```
$querystr = "SELECT comment_count, ID, post_title
        FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->comments wcomments
        WHERE wposts.ID = wcomments.comment_post_ID
        AND wposts.post_status='publish'
        AND wcomments.comment_approved='1'
        AND wcomments.comment_date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
        GROUP BY wposts.ID
        ORDER BY comment_count DESC
        LIMIT 0 ,  10
 ";
```

EDIT: Filter on date changed from YEAR to WEEK

Comment: The order by is on `comment_count`, a column of the posts table. The value in this column will not vary by the other conditions in the where clause.  I would not expect the date, status or approved filters to affect the count; they'll only filter out posts.

Comment: Good point, but comment count is set by the WordPress engine based upon the number of approved comments. The status and approved filters are in place so that posts that were commented on but not approved yet will be filtered out.

Comment: If you know that the filter on `comment_approved` doesn't do anything, why did you include it?  Also, the answer pretends to filter on `comment_date`, but it does not.  -1

Comment: comment_approved DOES do something. Did you try the query with / without? Without it will give you all the posts that have been commented even if they hadn't been approved. As for the date filter. To test it I put in YEAR instead of WEEK. As per in the question. I will edit it.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
global $wpdb;
$querystr = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT comment_count, ID,post_title 
    FROM $wpdb->posts 
    WHERE 
    post_status='publish' AND 
    post_date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
    ORDER BY comment_count DESC 
    LIMIT 0 , 10");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help... almost... See Jack's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're ordering by the `comment_count` field of the `posts` table.  Try ordering on the number of comments matched for the group:

```
ORDER BY count(*) desc
```